# What can cause a stage to reattempt in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following stages in Spark Web page (used with yarn):

[image]

The thing I'm surprised by the `Stage 0` retry 1, retry 2. What can cause such a thing?

I tried to reproduce it by myself and killed all executor processes (`CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend`) on one of my cluster machine, but all I got is some failed tasks with the description `Resubmitted (resubmitted due to lost executor)`.

What is the reason of the whole stage retry? And what's I'm curious about is that the number of Records read at each stage attempt was different:

[image]

and

[image]

Notice the `3011506` in the `Attempt 1` and `195907736` in the `Attempt 0`. Does stage retry cause Spark to re-reads some records twice?

Comment: In my experience, I saw "retry" was happening due to "Allocation Failure", which then, triggered GC to free-up some space. and then retry whole stage again.

Answer (score 6):

Stage failure might be due to the FetchFailure in Spark

**Fetch Failure:** Reduce task is not able to perform shuffle Read i.e. not able to locate shuffle file at disk written shuffle map task.

Spark will retry the stage if stageFailureCount < maxStageFailures otherwise It aborts the stage and corresponding Job.

https://youtu.be/rpKjcMoega0?t=1309

Answer (score 1):

Fetch Failure: Reduce task is not able to perform shuffle Read i.e. not able to locate shuffle file at disk written shuffle map task.